# Spring Boot Getting Startet 404 error

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle, spring-boot

I'm trying to use the spring framework for the first time. Unfortunately I'm getting 404-error when I call the URL of my webservice. Tomcat deployment of the war file is working (no errors in the logs).
When I execute the Example.java in eclipse everythings works fine.

Where is the mistake?

See my files/logs:

Example.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.5'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = 'myproject'
    version =  '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    //compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

log when starting the application inside eclipse

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::  (v2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

2017-06-01 16:22:17.745  INFO 14940 --- [           main] Example                                  : Starting Example on Laptop-Timo with PID 14940 (started by Timo in C:\Users\Timo\Documents\SE\Semester 4\LabSW\Webservice\TimeShoppingService)
2017-06-01 16:22:17.745  INFO 14940 --- [           main] Example                                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-01 16:22:17.815  INFO 14940 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6a01e23: startup date [Thu Jun 01 16:22:17 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-01 16:22:20.098  INFO 14940 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-01 16:22:20.116  INFO 14940 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-06-01 16:22:20.116  INFO 14940 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-06-01 16:22:20.264  INFO 14940 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-06-01 16:22:20.264  INFO 14940 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2449 ms
2017-06-01 16:22:20.626  INFO 14940 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-06-01 16:22:20.638  INFO 14940 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-01 16:22:20.639  INFO 14940 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-01 16:22:20.639  INFO 14940 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-01 16:22:20.640  INFO 14940 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-01 16:22:21.343  INFO 14940 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6a01e23: startup date [Thu Jun 01 16:22:17 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-01 16:22:21.442  INFO 14940 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto java.lang.String Example.home()
2017-06-01 16:22:21.456  INFO 14940 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-06-01 16:22:21.457  INFO 14940 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-06-01 16:22:21.548  INFO 14940 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-01 16:22:21.549  INFO 14940 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-01 16:22:21.683  INFO 14940 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-01 16:22:21.940  INFO 14940 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-06-01 16:22:22.018  INFO 14940 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-01 16:22:22.024  INFO 14940 --- [           main] Example                                  : Started Example in 4.81 seconds (JVM running for 5.487)
2017-06-01 16:22:32.727  INFO 14940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-06-01 16:22:32.727  INFO 14940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-06-01 16:22:32.755  INFO 14940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 28 ms
```

Comment: Which url you are using? it should looks like `http://localhost:8080`. Because your tomcat instance using 8080 port.

Comment: what is the webservice url you are calling ?

Comment: Sure. I'm using http://localhost:8080/Service/ ... "Service" is the name of my *.war file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` and just give request like

[localhost:8080/](http://localhost:8080/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy a spring-boot application to an external servlet container you need to extend [`SpringBootServletInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html).

The main method is only executed when the application is run standalone.
It is recommended to run spring-boot apps standalone rather than via an external servlet container, but it is possible to support both methods simultaneously.

[See the spring documentation for more information.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)

Answer (score 0):

By Default context path of Spring boot application is '/'. So in your case url to access home resource will be http://localhost:8080/

> For custom context path add an application.properties file to src\main\resources. In that properties file, add 2 properties:

`server.contextPath=/Service
 server.port=12378`

You may refer this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-change-context-path/9) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe url mistake. try it like the url below .

```
http://localhost:8080/Service/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mapped your controller or method with any specific string.

```
    @Controller
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class Example {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        @ResponseBody
        String home() {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
...
```

You have used `@RequestMapping("/")` which maps the `home()` method so you need to use `localhost:8080/` url instead of `localhost:8080/service` 
and if you want to use the `service` in url just change mapping to `@RequestMapping("/service")`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way out is just by replacing the annotation above the class respectively. And use the `@RestController`, then you move the `@RequestMapping("/")` above the class, Beneath the rest controller. Go to the Postman and call it with `localhost:8080/` and that's all